# Symbology: Unique Values populating all domain values

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, unique-value

I am working in ArcGIS Pro 2.8.5 with a polygon feature class that I want to symbolize using unique values. It is a domain constrained field with 1846 choices, but for the polygons in the feature class only 15 values are used. When I symbolize using unique values it wants to populate all of the domain values, or if I select not to load them all it just does the first 100. Is there a way I can have it only use the values present in the data?

Comment: Accept the initial 1846 then simply select them and remove them from the symbology. You can hold shift key to bulk select.